# Map different values in one list

Tags: c#, automapper

I have two classes, the source class

```
class DTO {
   TypeA objA;
   TypeB objB;
   ...
   ICollection<TypeZ> listZ;
}
```

and the destination class

```
class Entity {
   ICollection<TypeCommon> list;
}
```

I need an automapper config for this. I wrote separate configs from all Type* into TypeCommon. Now I need the config for the top level. The problem is, TypeCommon also contains the field "name", which should be mapped to the name of the source field ("objA", "objB" and so on). What would be the most simple way of doing this?

Comment: I think you might get an answer if you post some classes someone can work with, even if they're hypothetical. I can't look at this and understand what maps to what.